# How to render multi-line Text component with white gap between lines

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to replicate the following in React Native, a Text component with a *white gap* between lines.

```css
span {
  background: rgba(255, 235, 0);
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc at condimentum leo. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ut lorem ac tortor auctor laoreet. Fusce egestas orci quis dui egestas, ac malesuada lacus feugiat. Etiam at augue vel nisl luctus dignissim. Sed iaculis nec metus vitae interdum. Vivamus tincidunt fermentum ligula, eu tincidunt orci sodales at. Ut tristique velit erat, sed malesuada sapien ornare sit amet. Nunc congue imperdiet sapien in feugiat. Aenean id ipsum quis lorem rhoncus fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec ornare, risus in dictum dignissim, dui libero blandit velit, a fringilla ligula lacus quis purus. Vivamus ullamcorper lorem vel velit dignissim lacinia. Vestibulum pulvinar leo eget magna lacinia, sit amet porttitor risus cursus. Integer nec tincidunt orci. Proin maximus viverra arcu, sit amet bibendum diam sagittis ut.</span>
```

Adding the same CSS above to a `Text` component doesn't output the same as the above snippet.

Comment: How do you declare your style in react-native? can we have more of your code?

Comment: I declare them as a `StyleSheet` object. Here's an attempt at applying the same styles to a `Text` component https://snack.expo.io/r1NR1dd4Q

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment, React Native doesn't have this kind of styling out of the box. The CSS `line-height` property is not equivalent to `lineHeight` style prop of RN.

#### Lets take a look at iOS for example:

`lineHeight` is mapped to a a property of a paragraph style object that controls the min/max line height, which is then applied to your text. This line height is the whole fragment height, so any background color applied here will color the whole line.

There is another property of the native paragraph object called `lineSpacing` which is added after the line height is calculated. This property can actually control the space and would achieve the exact effect that you're after. Unfortunately, **RN doesn't give you control over this property**.

So, you can either find a package that provides this kind of functionality, or try to implement a native solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`Text` will not behave like a `span`. You can do a hack for this. Use [react-native-highlight-words](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words) lib and pass all text as `searchWords` first array element.

Comment: My only concern with this solution is that there will be white space between two 'highlighted' words.

Comment: Here is the working example: 
https://codepen.io/yakato/pen/EpbvbW
But you just need to test it in snack.expo.io instead of codepen

Comment: Did you try it? I've tested it in Expo on iOS and it works.

Comment: The output of your snippet doesn't include a white gap between the lines. I tried adding line-height to `highlightStyle` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lineHeight` instead of `line-height` in react native. 
If you want change gap color. this hack, set background color white for `Text`.

Comment: I have a Snack which uses `lineHeight` and a `backgroundColor` on `Text` - https://snack.expo.io/r1NR1dd4Q

Comment: @Dan What is problem in that

Comment: I am trying to render a white gap between the lines, as shown in the question.

Comment: You want render white gap with some background color?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. See the above, there's a `span` tag with text, it has a background colour and a white gap. I'd like to replicate exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `text` to be `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

Use flexWrap:"wrap" and lineHeight

```js
<View key={1} style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start', }}>
    <Text style={[styles.fonts_12_light_slate, { 
      flexWrap: 'wrap', lineHeight: 18, textAlign: 'left' }]}>
      LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM         LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM
    </Text>
</View>
```