# Render multi-line text component with white gap between lines with display:inline-block

Tags: css, inline

How can I render a multi-line text component with white gaps between the lines? The component must use `display: inline-block`.

I have a `<code>` tag with multi-line text. I was told not to change content or the `display` property, but to somehow make gaps between lines, so that the `background-color` property affects only one single line. Is it even possible with `display: inline-block`?

I found another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495351/how-to-render-multi-line-text-component-with-white-gap-between-lines), but the example there works with `display: inline`.

Here is what I'm trying to get:

```css
code {
  background-color: aqua;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<code>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humor and the like).</code>
```

Comment: The white gaps between lines are doable, the `background-color` property affecting a single line of a multi-line element, not so much. Use multiple spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider a gradient coloration that you combine with `inline-block`

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg,#0000 5px,aqua 0) 0 2px/100% 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<code>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humor and the like).</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember what "inline-block" means: the content **inside** the element will be displayed as a box (block), not inline. This will remove the white gaps between each line of text.

To display the gaps as desired, you can add a wrapper element inside the outer element.

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
}

code span {
  background-color: aqua;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* Make <code> sit next to the prior element */
code {
  max-width: 25em;
}
```

```html
<span>Some content</span>

<code>
  <span>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humor and the like).</span>
</code>
```